# Legend in network graph ( Highchart Js)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to show the user about which nodes are some sort of type in network graph of Highchart JS.

For example, the red node would be about "car" and the black node would be about "person".

How can I implement such a legend in Highchart Js?

[Here](https://codepen.io/w99910/pen/qBrWGRo) is my codepen.

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.networkgraph.prototype.drawLegendSymbol = Highcharts.LegendSymbolMixin.drawRectangle;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'networkgraph'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        networkgraph: {
            keys: ['from', 'to']
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
    series: [{
        showInLegend: true,
        data: [
            ['A', 'B'],
          ['C','D'],
          ['E','F']
        ],
      nodes:[{
        id:'A',
        color:'#ff1000'
      },{
        id:'B',
        color:'#222222'
      },
            {
        id:'C',
        color:'#ff1000'
      },
            {
        id:'D',
        color:'#222222'
      },
        {
        id:'E',
        color:'#ff1000'
      },
            {
        id:'F',
        color:'#222222'
      },]
    }]
});
```

Thank you in advance.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the `dataLabel` to `series` property and add a name to your nodes.

```
   {
      id: "A",
      color: "#ff1000",
      name: "car" <--------- name property
    },
```

Something like this:

```
 series: {
  dataLabels: {
    linkFormat: '',
    enabled: true,
    format: "{point.name}",
    crop: false,
    defer: false,
    useHtml: true,
  },
}
```

Full example:

https://codepen.io/tiagotedsky/pen/zYZYOLR

Comment: Thanks for your help. But unfortunately, it's not what I want. I have several nodes in my real chart and user will be disappointed by several labels over nodes. What I want is legend which will be placed top left of chart or bottom of chart and when user hover the legend ( let's say 'car' ) all car nodes will be highlighted. Is it possible to implement this? I haven't seen network graph chart examples with legends so far.

Comment: I guess you will need to update the chart when you filter, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/52m930hq/

Comment: That's really helpful. Thanks for it. Much appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use [dataClasses](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.dataClasses) for simple markers.
For complex markers, you can add some dummy series with type `bubble`.